# WPF - Binding a ComboBoxItem visibility using BooleanToVisibilityConverter

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, wpfdatagrid

I have a Datagrid, with a column that has a combobox in its header. I want to control the visibility of items in the combobox based on the value of a certain flag.

This is how my XAML looks:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="Table1" Height="{Binding ElementName=ElasticOne1,Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=ElasticOne1,Path=ActualWidth}" Padding="5,5,5,5" IsReadOnly="True"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Header="Source" Width="80">
      <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Margin="0">
            <StackPanel.Resources>              
              <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Margin="5"/>
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" >
              <ComboBoxItem Tag="0" IsSelected="True">All</ComboBoxItem>
              <ComboBoxItem Visibility="{Binding ShowCopybookInSourceCombobox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">Copybook</ComboBoxItem>
              <ComboBoxItem>Prototype</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

And this is the declaration of the flag in code:

```
Public ReadOnly Property ShowCopybookInSourceCombobox As Boolean
    Get
        Return myFlag1 Or myFlag2
    End Get
End Property
```

No matter what the value of my flag, the combobox item is always showing. I haven't seen any examples so far of binding the visibility of a comboboxitem this way. Am I on the wrong path?

Thanks for all your input.

Edit: BooleanToVisibilityConverter is a built-in class that I am using - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are going in right way. but have you checked what happens in the converter BoolToVis ? keep a break point and watch what is happening.

Comment: Make sure the converter returns Collapsed, not Hidden. Otherwise there will be a visible "gap".

Comment: Also, if the class your binding to doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the view may never be notified when your boolean property's value changes. Make sure you implement that interface and that you fire the `PropertyChanged` event whenever `myFlag1` or `myFlag2` values change.

Comment: BooleanToVisibilityConverter has no prefix indicating namespace. Show BooleanToVisibilityConverter implementation.

Comment: Thanks everyone! BooleanToVisibilityConverter is a built-in class - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx
Hence I assumed it worked as expected. The documentation says it returns Collapsed, not Hidden.
I am treating it as the next step to change the visibility of the item based on the change in myFlag1 and myFlag2. At this point, I just want to make the item visible/invisible based on the initial value.